# JMS messages to file in a reliable way

Tags: java, transactions, jms

I'm looking for a way to reliably retrieve messages from a JMS queue and store them into a flat file. By "reliably" I mean that in case of any failure (excluding failures of physical disks), possibly after system and processes are re-launched, I want:

1. to not lose any message and
2. to not have duplicate messages in my file.

What would be a good way for achieving this goal?

Context: WebLogic on Linux, receiving about 3000 messages/second for several hours.

Thanks -- Florian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you'll face is the file system; JMS supports JTA, but the file system does not. Consider the following:

```
public void onMessage(Message message){
  try{
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage)message;
    fileOutput.write( msg.getText());
    fileOutput.flush();

  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Assuming AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, each message received and serialized to the file will be auto acknowledged after `onMessage()` returns successfully. But the JMS server may crash before the acknowledgment is received, but after the message was written to the file; so you'll get a duplicate.

Instead of writing to a file, have you considered saving to a database, preferably one that has a XA driver? If so, you can use a distributed transaction between JMS and RDBMS, resulting in no message loss or duplicates.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, of course the problem is that a file system has no transactional capability. I need to write to a file, not to a database.
So I'd need somehow to implement a transactional scheme over the file system -- just what I need for my purpose. Is there any way (an API to implement?) to participate in a distributed transaction?

Comment: Yes, you can implement your own XA driver, but that's not trivial. Another option is to use a lightweight, local database, like HSQLDB, which supports XA. You can generate a file from the table that stores the messages on demand.

Comment: Ah... Another idea, just slightly different: write the data to flat file, and upon "commit" do: 1) flush file to disk, and transactionally: 2) write to an XA database the file pointer, 3) commmit changes in JMS queue. Rollback would be done by truncating the file back to where the XA database says the pointer is. Do you think this would work?

Comment: Oh, I see, so you save to the database only the position of where the last message was written to the file? Yes, that could work, I like that!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I guess I'll go with this. Some fun time ahead :)